# Grouping a list into sublists by key/attribute without changing the list order (just chop into lists by attrib)

Tags: c#, linq, list

I've hunted around for this, and I am sure that I am just missing it because I not that good with Linq.

I have a list that looks like:

```
type=a, value=aaaa
type=a, value=bbbb
type=b, value=cccc
type=d, value=dddd
type=d, value=eeee
type=d, value=ffff
type=a, value=gggg
type=b, value=hhhh
type=b, value=iiii
type=b, value=jjjj
```

I would like to break this into sub lists, without sorting (I need the original order maintained).  I would like to get back these lists, in this order in a list of lists or something similar:

```
List 1
type=a, value=aaaa
type=a, value=bbbb

List2
type=b, value=cccc

List 3
type=d, value=dddd
type=d, value=eeee
type=d, value=ffff

List 4
type=a, value=gggg

List 5
type=b, value=hhhh
type=b, value=iiii
type=b, value=jjjj
```

I would imagine that looping is not the best answer.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Long live stackoverflow.com!

Chris

Edit After Four Answers:

I checked the answers from:
    * Enigmativity
    * Bert Evans
    * Risky Martin
    * david.s

They all work nicely.  Bert Evans brought up performance, which isn't a big concern for me in this case, but I did some quick checking for the sake of the post.

I didn't modify anyone's code, just timed it doing 4,000 of these operations on rather short lists.

Risky's answer was the fastest.
Bert's answer was only a tad slower.

david's and Enigmativity were hardly any slower, really.

I marked Risky's answer as accepted because of performance and for pointing to the related post early on, and then coming back to provide an answer.

I would agree that Bert's is the most readable, though.

I honestly don't know which one I will use... actually, I will use Enigmativity's solution because it has already taken into account that i only need the values and one key per subgroup.

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11512898/480799) a related discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be generalized or made into an extension method, but you get the idea:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<Item>> GroupConsecutive(IEnumerable<Item> items)
{
    if (items.Any())
    {
        string firstType = items.Select(i => i.Type).First();
        var adjacents = items.TakeWhile(i => i.Type == firstType).ToList();
        yield return adjacents;
        foreach (var group in GroupConsecutive(items.Skip(adjacents.Count)))
        {
            yield return group;
        }
    }
}
```

Using this class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: Here are the tradeoffs for this solution:

Pros:

- Returns a lazily evaluated collection
- Doesn't mutate any variables
- Is concise

Cons:

- Iterates through `items` twice. This isn't a big deal if `items` is a List, but if `items` is an IEnumerable that performs an expensive computation for each item, this method could be slower than other methods.

If you want `items` to be iterated once with lazy evaluation, I recommend the [GroupAdjacent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/04/21/the-groupadjacent-extension-method.aspx) extension method as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11514313/480799) answer or looping with `yield return`.  If you want one iteration without lazy evaluation, I recommend looping or the `Aggregate` method.

Comment: @chrismead I listed the tradeoffs for this solution along with recommendations for alternative solutions based on what one wants.  I hope this helps with your decision!

Answer (score 4):

Using a slightly modified extension method from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478070/how-to-group-consecutive-similar-items-of-a-collection/2528167#2528167) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881363/smart-grouping-with-linq):

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, T>> GroupConsecutive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> set, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    var i = 0;
    var k = 0;
    var ranges = from e in set
                    let idx = ++i
                    let next = set.ElementAtOrDefault(idx)
                    let key = next == null ? k : predicate(e, next) ? k : k++
                    group e by key into g
                    select g;
    return ranges;
}
```

And given a class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

You can do this:

```
List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>()
{
    new Foo() { Type = "a", Value = "aaaa" },
    new Foo() { Type = "a", Value = "bbbb" },
    new Foo() { Type = "b", Value = "cccc" },
    new Foo() { Type = "d", Value = "dddd" },
    new Foo() { Type = "d", Value = "eeee" },
    new Foo() { Type = "d", Value = "ffff" },
    new Foo() { Type = "a", Value = "gggg" },
    new Foo() { Type = "b", Value = "hhhh" },
    new Foo() { Type = "b", Value = "iiii" },
    new Foo() { Type = "b", Value = "jjjj" }
};

var groups = list.GroupConsecutive((a, b) => a.Type == b.Type);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("List " + group.Key);
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type=" + item.Type + "    Value=" + item.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

And the result would look like this:

```
List 0
Type=a    Value=aaaa
Type=a    Value=bbbb

List 1
Type=b    Value=cccc

List 2
Type=d    Value=dddd
Type=d    Value=eeee
Type=d    Value=ffff

List 3
Type=a    Value=gggg

List 4
Type=b    Value=hhhh
Type=b    Value=iiii
Type=b    Value=jjjj
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a LINQ only answer using `Aggregate`.

I started with this:

```
var list = new []
{
    new { type="a", value="aaaa", },
    new { type="a", value="bbbb", },
    new { type="b", value="cccc", },
    new { type="d", value="dddd", },
    new { type="d", value="eeee", },
    new { type="d", value="ffff", },
    new { type="a", value="gggg", },
    new { type="b", value="hhhh", },
    new { type="b", value="iiii", },
    new { type="b", value="jjjj", },
};
```

And then did this:

```
var accumulator = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(
        list.First().type,
        new List<string>()),
};

var results = list.Aggregate(accumulator, (a, x) =>
{
    if (a.Last().Key == x.type)
    {
        a[a.Count - 1].Value.Add(x.value);
    }
    else
    {
        a.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(
            x.type,
            new List<string>(new [] { x.value, })));
    }
    return a;
});
```

The `results` then look like this:

[image: results]

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

No LINQ, plain old c# and a single loop every junior developer could hopefully follow.  Not to mention faster.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>()
{
    new Foo() { Type = "a", Value = "aaaa" },
    new Foo() { Type = "a", Value = "bbbb" },
    new Foo() { Type = "b", Value = "cccc" },
    new Foo() { Type = "d", Value = "dddd" },
    new Foo() { Type = "d", Value = "eeee" },
    new Foo() { Type = "d", Value = "ffff" },
    new Foo() { Type = "a", Value = "gggg" },
    new Foo() { Type = "b", Value = "hhhh" },
    new Foo() { Type = "b", Value = "iiii" },
    new Foo() { Type = "b", Value = "jjjj" }
};

Foo previous = null;
List<List<Foo>> separateLists = new List<List<Foo>>();
List<Foo> currentList = null;
foreach (var foo in list)
{
    if (null == previous || previous.Type != foo.Type)
    {
        currentList = new List<Foo>();
        separateLists.Add(currentList);
    }
    currentList.Add(foo);
    previous = foo;
}
```